# URLs (links) placed in a HTML list

Tags: support, hyperlinks

Do the below formatted/styled URLs (links) placed in a HTML list not work due to mixing two different markup formats when composing a post?

- [Composting Council of Canada][1]
- [Create Your Own Compost Pile][2]
- [Making and Using Compost][3]
- [US Composting Council][4]

Answer (score 4):

If, while typing out your post, you click the little question-mark that appears above and to the right, you'll get a handy-dandy Markdown reference. Clicking on HTML provides this illuminating text:

> Block-level HTML elements have a few restrictions:
>
> 1. They must be separated from surrounding text by blank lines.
> 2. The begin and end tags of the outermost block element must not be indented.
> 3. **Markdown can't be used within HTML blocks.**

(emphasis mine)

So you can use whatever links you want, *if* you use a Markdown-style list (wanna know how? Go back to the Markdown reference and select "Lists"!) but if you use a HTML list (`<ul></ul>` or `<ol></ol>`) you'll have to use HTML links (`<a></a>`) within it.

It occurs to me at this point that some readers might not know how to distinguish between span-level HTML and block-level HTML... Span-level doesn't necessarily end up in a separate paragraph (bold, italics, links...) while block-level will (lists, code blocks, quotes...)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities:

1. You may be running into a limit based on your rep. I think low-rep users can only have a couple of links per post to prevent spammy answers. Once you get a few more upvotes I think the number of links you can include increases. At the moment I can't find a reference to this limitation.
2. There appears to be a bug related to mixing link types. I can't find a reference to it, but in a comment on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95165/markdown-not-correctly-generating-links/95170#95170), Jeff Atwood mentions a bug that balpha says will be fixed in the next build.

This HTML list:

- [example 1](http://example.com)
- [example 2][1]
- [example 3](http://example.com)

has the three kinds of links I can figure out how to add. They all render ok until I add the "</ul>" on the end of the list, and then the markdown links don't work. At any rate, if this isn't already a known bug, you would be best to report it at [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) instead of here.

FWIW, if you want to make bullets, markdown is easier than HTML. Just put "*" at the start of the line and you'll get a UL.

Comment: I don't think #1 is the problem (at east in my case), as I was able to post those 4 links in this post: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-i-add-water-to-my-compost-heap/1093#1093

Comment: #2 might be relevant in my case or it could be as simple as you can't use mixed markup formats to construct the kind of list I was after creating. I honestly don't know, hence posting my question here...

Comment: @Mike - Ok, then the rep threshold for links must be low. My guess is #2.

Comment: _FWIW, if you want to make bullets, markdown is easier than HTML. Just put "*" at the start of the line and you'll get a UL._ <-- Thank you, I did stumble into that easier (correct) solution myself while playing around with lists containing URLs. And thank you for your detailed answer, it's much appreciated.